# Store CPU utilization into CSV file

Tags: debian, shell-script, cpu, top, cpu-usage

OS: Debian 8 x64

I'd like to log every 5 seconds the CPU percentage into a CSV file in the format below:

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS,CPU%
```

I'm not familiar with how to use the `top` program to calculate the ((us+sy)/(us+sy+id)*100) using awk/grep. Would appreciate help in doing so.

Through my searches, I saw a few examples of people using top -bn1 and top -bn2. However, if my loop is calling top, I'd assume I wouldn't need to use batch mode at all.

Here's the shell script I started to write.

```
#!/bin/bash

while sleep 5; do "top | grep "Cpu(s)" | awk '{}' >> cpu.csv; done
```

Comment: If you're not interested in per-process statistics, you may want to consider the CPU fields of `vmstat` or `mpstat` (which can be polled at specified intervals without resorting to an explicit shell loop e.g. `vmstat 5 | awk ...`)

Comment: How can I do this with vmstat?

Comment: are you limited to top? you can consider using atop instead, it has a batch logging mode

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via `vmstat`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

open VMSTAT, "vmstat 5|";
<VMSTAT>; <VMSTAT>; # skip the header
while (<VMSTAT>) {
    @now = split;
    ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = localtime (time);
    printf "%d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d,%d%\n", $year+1900, $mon, $mday, $hour, $min, $sec,
        $now[12] + $now[13];
}
```

Most of the code is for printing out the date...

Answer (score 0):

1) Let's compare the following two versions:

```
while sleep 0.1 ; do top -d 10 | grep Cpu ; done
#versus batch mode
while sleep 0.1 ; do top -d 10 -bn1 | grep Cpu ; done
```

You will see that in the first example the time is defined by `top`'s update interval ( set to 10 seconds via `-d 10`), while in the second the `sleep` command in the while loop is the limit. Note that also `top` never finishes in the first example, which makes processing any piped output a problem, as the program that reads from `stin` never gets a "process ended" signal which especially is a problem for column-based programs like `awk` or `cut`. See how e.g.

```
top -d 0.1 -b | grep Cpu | cut -d' ' -f1
```

will not produce output at the intervals `top` produces it, but rather in irregular batches, while

```
while sleep 0.1 ; do top -bn1 | grep Cpu | cut -d' ' -f1 ; done
```

produces output at desired intervals.

Long story short: DO use you `while` loop AND `top -bn1`

2) `awk` processing:

With `stin` read from `top -bn1 | grep Cpu`, you can use:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS == " +" } ; { cmd1="date +%Y-%m-%d" ; cmd2="date +%H:%M:%S" ; while ( cmd1 | getline a ) ; while ( cmd2 | getline b) ; print a,b,($2+$4)/($2+$4+$8)*100"%" }'
```

As `BEGIN { FS == " +" }` will use one or more (`+`) spaces as field separators, the respective fields for us,sy, and id are $2,$4, and $8.

The workaround with `cmd1="..." ; while ( cmd1 | getline a)` is necessary to read a system call's result as variable in awk. See @ghostdog74's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960895/awk-assigning-system-commands-output-to-variable)

Comment: Why is the output always provide the same percentage no matter the current load or stress test?

Comment: I see what's wrong. $2 $4 and $8 are all printing wrong output. Top is showing 0 idle and the script is showing 94% idle.

Comment: hmm, my `top -bn1 | grep Cpu` output looks like `%Cpu(s):  9.7 us,  3.4 sy,  0.0 ni, 70.5 id, 16.2 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.2 si,  0.0 st` , so I used $2, $4, and $8. What do those columns show for you?

Answer (score -1):

I would say that proposed solutions are overkill. This should do...

```
echo $(date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,' && uptime | awk '{print "CPU: " $9*100 "%"}' ) >> myfile.csv
```

Of course put this in while loop together with desired sleep time.

It takes CPU load from "uptime" command, which is equal as "top" load and appends it to a file.

BR,
Neven

Comment: Load average is not CPU usage, see eg. http://stackoverflow.com/a/21621256/1142595 for details.

Comment: @FerencWágner: True it isn't, my bad.